# Translate animation works perfectly when defining with XML and only once perfectly by code - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I'm getting this weird issue. Basically I'm animating a view with translate animation. (Translate into the screen and out via 2 different events) My code for translate animation is:

```
    final Animation  animtopOut = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -mainHeaderlayout.getMeasuredHeight());
                    animtopOut.setDuration(500);
                    animtopOut.setFillAfter(true);
mainHeaderlayout.setAnimation(animtopOut);
```

And the xml code is:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >

<translate 
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="-99%p"
    android:duration="600"
    android:fillAfter="true">

</translate>
</set>
```

Setting it using the code:

```
final Animation animtopOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.header_animate_out);
```

When I trigger the animation it works fine if I use the xml animation properties. **The problem is when i use it via code. Which is what I want. It runs with translate animation only for the first time.** The second time, when it is triggered, the view is inside the screen without animation. Please some one help me if I'm missing any properties. Thanks.

---

**EDIT : (extra info)**

There are actually two different animations that are triggered on the same view via two different events. I have actually posted one animation property. The other is almost the same. with just values are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried animation configuration like this

```
animtopOut.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

animtopOut.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);

animtopOut.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```

?

Comment: In my case this line made my day: animtopOut.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());